# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using **Laravel Auth** to register and login my users into the respective dashboard. `I am using admin as my user`. I created the migration for admin, but when i try to register my admin error comes `Table or view not found` and the table which is not found is the built in table users which i deleted because i was not using that one. I have to use the admin table please help me how can i remove this error.

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'fyp.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select count() as aggregate from users where email =**********)

Comment: try this comman php artisan migrate:refresh and you should define table manually protected $table = 'your_table_name';

Comment: @AhmadHassan it still gives this error when i try to register my user

Comment: do you create model file for admin if it is them add this line protected $table = 'your_table_name';

Comment: @AhmadHassan i should add this line in my model

Comment: yes! you should add if you create manually table.

Comment: protected $table = 'admin';

Comment: @AhmadHassan still giving error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155623/discussion-between-ahmad-hassan-and-nida-akram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some possibilities that i have mention below:

1) In the config/auth.php change the users model to your company class.

```
   'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
```

2) In the Admin class, define fillable and hidden fields:

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable {

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

3) Do not forget to change validation in **registerContoller.**

```
'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:admins',
```

4)Clear the config cache or rebuild it:

```
 php artisan config:clear  
 php artisan config:cache
```

References:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/change-users-table-name

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/changing-users-table-name-52

Answer (score 0):

Edit app/config/auth.php to change the table.

```
'table' => 'admin',
```

Source: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/12/changing-your-authentication-table

EDIT: That was for Laravel 4. For Laravel 5, it depends on the driver you're using. If you're using Eloquent, you can change the default model in your config/auth.php file here:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class, // Here you can change the users model
    ],
],
```

or you can specify the right table in the `App\User` model.

If you're using the database driver, you can change the name of the table in the same way:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'users',  // Here you can change the database table
    ],
],
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: There is not any table attribute in my auth.php file

Comment: I'm sorry, I gave you an answer for Laravel 4. I'm updating the answer.

Comment: I have changed model to the model i created for admin and added their protected $table = 'admins'; but still the same error when i try to register my user